# Limit in a function defined on (ir)rationals

Tags: limits

I know that Limits can't be defined in function whose domain is Natural or Integer, when x approches any finite value.

By the way, limits can be defined in a function whose domain is set of rationals or irrationals?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, limits can be defined for functions whose domain is rational. Use the same definition as usual but replace all real numbers by rationals. One huge difference is that Cauchy sequences in $\mathbb{Q}$ are not necessarily convergent.